# Force gcc not to inline a function

Tags: c++, gcc

I try to stop gcc from inlining a function the following way:

```
template <typename T, precision P> __attribute__ ((noinline))
void func () {}
```

But it still inlines the function.

Is there a way to force it?

Regards

Comment: @Michael - But the answer *there* is exactly what the OP tries *here*.

Comment: Is the function empty? If it is, gcc doesn't _inline_ it, it optimizes it away completely.

Comment: What tkausl said. Adding *something* to the function shows that `noinline` works fine. https://godbolt.org/z/LA2kA3

Comment: Comparison between empty and non-empty function: https://godbolt.org/z/reFJlH

Comment: is this the answer? The code you tried to not inline is an empty function or is the code you posted here just a simplified version of some other code?

Comment: @VictorGubin - Or before. It's flexible.

Comment: @VictorGubin Only attribute after the parameter declaration list are attribute of the function type, other with they are attribute of the entity(ies) being declared.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by preventing this empy function from being inlined? This seems to be an xy problem.

Answer (score 5):

Make gcc believe this function has side effects:

```
template <typename T, precision P> __attribute__ ((noinline))
void func () {
    asm volatile("");
}
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/0roSiO)

Answer (score 2):

[`__attribute__((noipa))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-noipa-function-attribute) disables more optimizations than just inlining. In particular, it also disables the optimization that notices that the function is pure (and thus calls can be removed unless the returned value is used). The documentation for [`__attribute__((noinline))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-noinline-function-attribute) explicitly mentions empty functions and the need to add for instance `asm("");` so they are not optimized away.